# Alamofire 4, Swift 3: Can not return StatusCode

Tags: json, swift, http, post, alamofire

This gives an error: "Escaping closures can only capture inout ..."

How can I fix it?

```
func check_info(tag: String, info: String, code: inout Int) {

    Alamofire.request(
        URL + "/api/test_information/",
        method: .post,
        parameters: [tag: info],
        encoding: JSONEncoding.default
    ).responseString { response in
        code = (response.response?.statusCode)!
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited: If you want to return the status code, use this callback function. The callback with return the status code as soon as you get a response.

```
func check_info(tag: String, info: String, statusCode: @escaping (String)->Void){
Alamofire.request(URL + "/api/test_information/", method: .post, parameters: [tag: info], encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
            statusCode((response.response?.statusCode)!)
        }
    }
```

And to call it, use:

```
check_info(tag: "yourtag", info: "yourInfo){
    statusCode in
        print(statusCode)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I need to use this value in another function

Comment: @MarkYankovsky Check now, with this callback function it should work. Didn't test it myself, but that's the way I use it

Comment: Thanks, but how can I call this func? I've never used @escaping?

Comment: @MarkYankovsky Sorry, i completely forgot that part. Just edited my answer. You catch the escaped values using a kind of completion block. That completion block will be called when the Alamofire request completes.